# pgfplots: How to add time axis as second x-axis?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, datetime, axis

I preprocessed a series of data into a `time` column and a further column with `time distance to zero`, the latter as decimal value.

---

**Minimum Working Example (MWE):**

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
    Date;Time;Time_numeric;Temp_1;Temp_2
    16.03.2019;18:48:24;0;30;69
    16.03.2019;18:48:54;0.008;31;68
    16.03.2019;18:49:24;0.017;32;67
    16.03.2019;18:49:54;0.025;33;66
    16.03.2019;18:50:24;0.033;34;65
    16.03.2019;18:50:54;0.042;35;64
    16.03.2019;18:51:24;0.05;36;63
    16.03.2019;18:51:54;0.058;37;62
    16.03.2019;18:52:24;0.067;38;61
    16.03.2019;18:52:54;0.075;39;60
    16.03.2019;18:53:24;0.083;40;59
    16.03.2019;18:53:54;0.092;41;58
    16.03.2019;18:54:24;0.1;42;57
    16.03.2019;18:54:54;0.108;43;56
    16.03.2019;18:55:24;0.117;44;55
    16.03.2019;18:55:54;0.125;45;54
    16.03.2019;18:56:24;0.133;46;53
    16.03.2019;18:56:54;0.142;47;52
    16.03.2019;18:57:24;0.15;48;51
    16.03.2019;18:57:54;0.158;49;50
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[axis y line*  = left,
              table/col sep = semicolon]%
            \addplot table[x=Time_numeric,y=Temp_1]{data.csv};
 \end{axis}%
 %
 \begin{axis}[axis x line   = none,
              axis y line*  = right,
              table/col sep = semicolon]%
            \addplot table[x=Time_numeric,y=Temp_2]{data.csv};
 \end{axis}%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

**Screenshot of the result:**

[image: Screenshot of the result]

---

**Question:**

How can I display the time column as a second x-axis above the diagram? As you can imagine, the "real" time column and the column "time distance to zero" should match their lines.

- The top x-axis should display the real time in format 18:48:24
- The bottom x-axis should display the numeric value like seen above

---

**Screenshot of the desired state:**

[image: Screenshot of the desired state]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it.

---

**Minimum Working Example (MWE):**

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot, statistics}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.txt}
Date;Time_numeric;Temp_1;Temp_2
2019-03-16 18:48:24;0;30 ;69
2019-03-16 18:48:54;0.008 ;31 ;68
2019-03-16 18:49:24;0.017 ;32 ;67
2019-03-16 18:49:54;0.025 ;33 ;66
2019-03-16 18:50:24;0.033 ;34 ;65
2019-03-16 18:50:54;0.042 ;35 ;64
2019-03-16 18:51:24;0.05 ;36 ;63
2019-03-16 18:51:54;0.058 ;37 ;62
2019-03-16 18:52:24;0.067 ;38 ;61
2019-03-16 18:52:54;0.075 ;39 ;60
2019-03-16 18:53:24;0.083 ;40 ;59
2019-03-16 18:53:54;0.092 ;41 ;58
2019-03-16 18:54:24;0.1 ;42 ;57
2019-03-16 18:54:54;0.108 ;43 ;56
2019-03-16 18:55:24;0.117 ;44 ;55
2019-03-16 18:55:54;0.125 ;45 ;54
2019-03-16 18:56:24;0.133 ;46 ;53
2019-03-16 18:56:54;0.142 ;47 ;52
2019-03-16 18:57:24;0.15 ;48 ;51
2019-03-16 18:57:54;0.158 ;49 ;50
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
%
    \begin{axis}[   axis x line*        = bottom,
                    table/col sep       = semicolon                         ]%
                    \addplot table[x=Time_numeric,y=Temp_1]{data.txt};
    \end{axis}
%
    \begin{axis}[   axis x line*        = top,
                    axis y line         = none,
                    date coordinates in = x,
                    table/col sep       = comma,
                    date ZERO           = 2019-03-16 18:48:24,
                    table/col sep       = semicolon,
                    xticklabel          = \hour:\minute,                    ]%
                    \addplot [draw=none] table[x=Date,y=Temp_1] {data.txt};
    \end{axis}
%
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

---

**Screenshot of the result:**

[image: Screenshot of the result]

---

Important: The graph of the "numeric" x-axis and the graph of the "datetime" x-axis should have the same data extent, otherwise the lines won't match.